# How to auto convert on user TimeZone using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this format date:

**Sunday 20:30 America/Toronto**

i want every time a user access the page with the date to get auto timezone convert that date but i only want to convert and display for example this format Sunday 20:30 .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) alongside with [timeZoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) and this will get the desired behaviour.

For example:

```
var tz = jstz.determine();
var userTimeZone = tz.name();
//you can use any date format here you want
var currentTime    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/Toronto"); // time defined in Toronto timezone
var userTime = newYork.clone().tz(userTimeZone);
```